# hibernate: OneToMany RelationShip: Entity table not accepting multiple values

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

**Can any one help me out in my hibernate program where i'm trying to implement OneToMany Entity Relationship. i successfully resolve many error/exceptions from step one and now stuck in this Mysql exception and trying to resolve since 2 days**

### [image]

*I just want to do something like this*

[image]

*I mention step-by-step what i done*

### * Table creation

```
  create table area(acode varchar(100) not null, aname varchar(50) default null, primary key(acode));

   create table employee (acode varchar(100) not null,ecode varchar(50) not null, primary key(ecode), name varchar(50) default null,  key employee_foregin(acode),  constraint employee_foregin foreign key(acode) references area(acode));
```

- Adding maven dependencies*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mishra.practice</groupId>
    <artifactId>HibernateDemo_1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

- Area Entity*

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Area {
    @Id
    private String aCode;
    private String aName;
    @ManyToOne
    private Employee employee;

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }
    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }
    public String getaCode() {
        return aCode;
    }
    public void setaCode(String aCode) {
        this.aCode = aCode;
    }
    public String getaName() {
        return aName;
    }
    public void setaName(String aName) {
        this.aName = aName;
    }

    public Area() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Area(String aCode, String aName) {
        super();
        this.aCode = aCode;
        this.aName = aName;
    }

    public Area(String aCode) {
        super();
        this.aCode = aCode;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Area [aCode=" + aCode + ", aName=" + aName  + "]";
    }


}
```

- Employee Entity*

```
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private String eCode;
    private String eName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    private Collection<Area> areas;

    public Collection<Area> getAreas() {
        return areas;
    }

    public void setAreas(Collection<Area> areas) {
        this.areas = areas;
    }

    public String geteCode() {
        return eCode;
    }

    public void seteCode(String eCode) {
        this.eCode = eCode;
    }

    public String geteName() {
        return eName;
    }

    public void seteName(String eName) {
        this.eName = eName;
    }

    public Employee() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Employee(String eCode, String eName, Collection<Area> areas) {
        super();
        this.eCode = eCode;
        this.eName = eName;
        this.areas = areas;

    }

    public Employee(String eCode, String eName) {
        super();
        this.eCode = eCode;
        this.eName = eName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [eCode=" + eCode + ", eName=" + eName + "]";
    }

}
```

- Area Entry

```
package relationMapping.one_2_Many;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class AreaEntry {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration configuration=new Configuration().configure();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session= sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction= session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(new Area("A111", "Indore_North"));
        session.save(new Area("A112", "Indore_South"));
        session.save(new Area("A113", "Indore_East"));
        session.save(new Area("A114", "Bhopal_south"));
        session.save(new Area("A115", "Bhopal_central"));

        transaction.commit();
        System.out.println("\n----------------All done-------------------");
        session.close();
    }
}
```

- Employee Entry

```
package relationMapping.one_2_Many;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class EmployeeEntry {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration configuration=new Configuration().configure();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session= sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction= session.beginTransaction();

        List<Area> list1=new ArrayList<Area>();
        list1.add(new Area("A101"));
        list1.add(new Area("A102"));
        session.persist(new Employee("E101", "Narendra",list1));



        List<Area> list2=new ArrayList<Area>();
        list2.add(new Area("A103"));
        list2.add(new Area("A104"));
        session.persist(new Employee("E102", "Nik", list2));

        List<Area> list3=new ArrayList<Area>();
        list3.add(new Area("A105"));
        list3.add(new Area("A104"));
        session.persist(new Employee("E103","Pradeep",list3));

        List<Area> list4=new ArrayList<Area>();
        list4.add(new Area("A104"));
        list4.add(new Area("A105"));
        session.persist(new Employee("E104", "Chetan", list4));

        List<Area> list5=new ArrayList<Area>();
        list5.add(new Area("A105"));
        list5.add(new Area("A101"));
        session.persist(new Employee("E105", "Dev", list5));

        transaction.commit();
        System.out.println("\n----------------All done-------------------");
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in you DDL for the Employee table you define a column `acode`

```
   create table employee (acode varchar(100) not null,ecode varchar(50) not null, primary key(ecode), name varchar(50) default null,  key employee_foregin(acode),  constraint employee_foregin foreign key(acode) references area(acode));
```

This column isn't mapped to anything in your Employee Entity class (You have a column named ecode however)

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private String eCode;
```

And that's basically what the error message is telling you (Unknown column)

So change the ecode to acode in the Employee entity class.
By the way, you should let Spring generate your Database tables for you to avoid such problems.

Comment: eCode is primary key for employee entity and if change it to aCode then how my employee entity can save it's primary key.

Comment: i think problem is in my employee entity it's not taking area(aCode) from collection instance. hence it shows this sql exception, but i already mention "Collection<Area> acode " on my employee entity